# I need to avoid double splash screen issue in android- 12 API Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**SplashActivity.cs**

```
namespace Splash12.Droid
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashActivity).Name;

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
            Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
        }

        // Launches the startup task
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
            startupWork.Start();
        }

        // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
        async void SimulateStartup()
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Performing some startup work that takes a bit of time.");
            await Task.Delay(8000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Startup work is finished - starting MainActivity.");
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }
     }
}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "Splash12", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

}

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>
```

**splash_screen.xml**

Comment: I've never heard of anyone ending up with a double splash screen. When I google `xamarin android splash screen`, I see many links that look promising. You shouldn't have to resort to translating java to c#. (And if you do, *you* need to learn how to do that hand-translation. This question becomes appropriate for StackOverflow only once you've attempted, and gotten stuck on a line that you can't figure out.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because StackOverflow is not a code translation service.

Comment: I reproduced your code and it worked well on my side. These codes have no problem. There only one splash screen on my device. So can you provide a demo?

Answer (score 3):

In Android 12, it has its own splash screen and this is the Android way to provide a loading view for waiting the application to launch.

So, you add another splash screen cause the issue that you have two splash screens.

For solving the issue, you can add the code below to your `style.xml`.

```
<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

This code `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` can make the splash screen of the Android 12 become transparent. So you can only see your splash screen instead.

Comment: Again this is not correct for Android 12. Please see the migration docs I referred to earlier.

Comment: But this is an effective method to solve the double splash screen issue.

Comment: There wouldn't be a double splash issue if you followed the documentation, so your answer is incorrect. How about at least updating your theme? You are suggesting AppCompat when at least it should be Theme.MaterialComponents.* for Android12 and above.

Comment: This solution is a workable hack, but not the correct solution.  One should refer to the migration doc shared by @user2153142

Answer (score 2):

That is not the way to do a splash screen on Android 12.

Check out the example XamarinBasicSplashScreen at https://github.com/gmck/XamarinBasicSplashScreen.

For further documentation https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate